# Is there any windows phone opacityMask-like tech in android?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7

OpacityMask is useful in windows phone application dev, it make it easy to change the icon color when change themes(dark/light), or change the control icon color in different state, with just one image. 
Is there any windows phone opacityMask-like tech in android ?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly - but you could load up the bitmap containing the image and compose a new bitmap that contains the blended result of that image and one containing a solid color (generated procedurally). You can use the technique shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605325/blending-pixels-from-two-bitmaps).

Hope this helps!